# automatically publishing blog to LinkedIn

Tags: professionalism, linkedin, blogging

Is it considered professional to publish new blog entries to LinkedIn?

The content of the blog is technical in nature and relevant to my field. It is not questionable nor objectionable.

<sub>Typical frequency of new entries in my blog is once sometimes twice a month.</sub>

Comment: how often do you intend to publish new blog entries? I for one recall turning off notifications on updates from LinkedIn connections that felt like too frequent to me

Comment: @gnat Typical frequency is once sometimes twice a month.

Comment: that sounds safe; I for one don't turn off updates from connections if these come like you describe. I even sometimes read these :)

Comment: It sounds like it's a professional blog (ie, content related to your profession) so I don't see why it would be bad from that perspective. I'm not convinced LinkedIn is a great social platform, but that's another discussion, I suppose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the blog is well written (i.e. free from typos and grammatically correct), technically correct (with appropriate levels of expertise) and adds something relevant to your industry that did not previously exist (there is no sense in rehashing an existing article if you don’t add a new perspective / level of expertise) then I would say go for it!

On the whole employers are looking for something to differentiate a candidate from their peers, and writing a blog / articles can be an exceptional way to do this as long as care is taken to make sure that you come across in the best possible (and professional) light.